# Use jquery to set value of div tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html div tag defined:

```
<div style="height:100px; width:100px" class="total-title">
    first text
</div>
```

I have jquery code to change its value:

```
 $('div.total-title').html('test');
```

But this does not change the content of the div.

Comment: Where exactly do you execute the statement: $('div.total-title').html('test'); ??

Comment: Theres absolutely nothing wrong with the code, if you calling the js-code after the DOM is ready. Farzad, answered it correctly.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

if your value is a pure text (like 'test') you could use the text() method as well. like this:

```
$('div.total-title').text('test');
```

anyway, about the problem you are sharing, I think you might be calling the JavaScript code before the HTML code for the DIV is being sent to the browser. make sure you are calling the jQuery line in a <script> tag after the <div>, or in a statement like this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('div.total-title').text('test');
    }
);
```

this way the script executes after the HTML of the div is parsed by the browser.

Comment: When i put it like div.total-value it was not working. But after making it like #total-value it works

Comment: why do you need to rap it around an anonymous function? will it work without it?

Comment: Because the page hasn't set up yet if it hasn't finished loading, so the div may not even exist yet if you simply put the raw code in the top level of, say, the <head>.

Comment: either the ready or the anonymous function is required, to delay the evaluation.  In this redundant case I believe the code is overkill, but it encourages cut & paste software maintainers to avoid mistakes later on.

Comment: yep, I think it should be `$('#div.total-title').text('test');`

Answer (score 11):

To put text, use `.text('text')`

If you want to use `.html(SomeValue)`, SomeValue should have html tags that can be inside a div it must work too.

Just check your script location, as farzad said.

Reference: [.html](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html#val) and [text](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text#val)

Answer (score 5):

try this function `$('div.total-title').text('test');`

Comment: text is obsolete now, for v1.4 or back.

Answer (score 4):

You have referenced the jQuery JS file haven't you? There's no reason why farzad's answer shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `.html()` method, a `htmlString` must be the parameter. ([source](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)) Put your string inside a HTML tag and it should work or use `.text()` as suggested by farzad.

Example:

```
<div class="demo-container">
    <div class="demo-box">Demonstration Box</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("div.demo-container").html( "<p>All new content. <em>You bet!</em></p>" );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use as below:

`<div id="getSessionStorage"></div>`

For this to append anything use below code for reference:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var storageVal = sessionStorage.getItem("UserName");
        alert(storageVal);
        $("#getSessionStorage").append(storageVal);
     });
```

This will appear as below in html (assuming storageVal="Rishabh")

```
<div id="getSessionStorage">Rishabh</div>
```